# Regex: Replacing all spaces between two characters

Tags: r, regex

Consider the following string: `This is an example: this is another one, and this is yet another, and other, and so on.`
I want to replace all space characters between `:` and `,`. So it would look like this `This is an example:_this_is_another_one, and this is yet another, and other, and so on.`

What I've tried so far:

- `(?<=:)\s+(?=[^,]*,)` (only matches the first space)
- `:\s+(?=[^:,]*,)` (Same as above)
- `\s+(?=[^:,]*,)` (Matches `This is an example:_this_is_another_one,_and_this_is_yet_another,_and_other, and so on`)

Comment: I don't think non-PCRE regex can do this without string functions or multiple regular expressions. In a single regular expression, however, you could use `(?:(?<=:)|\G(?!\A)) ([^\s,]*)` and substitute with `_$1`, but I don't believe r's regular expressions support this

Comment: Should the `,` be present by all means? Or do you also want to replace the spaces up to the end of string if there is no comma?

Comment: @ctwheels You may use a PCRE regex with R `gsub`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for confirming that, wasn't sure which flavour R uses.

Comment: @ctwheels PCRE is used with base R and some other libraries using `perl=TRUE` argument, else base R uses TRE regex library, and some other libraries use Tcl regex engine. *stringr*/*stringi* uses ICU regex library. It is a regex engine nightmare.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree; a nightmare. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: there is a simple way to replace anything in between arbitrary strings in R using `stringr::str_replace_all` using an anonymous function as the replacement argument:

**Generic `stringr` approach**

```
library(stringr)

# left - left boundary
# right - right boundary
# x - input
# what - regex pattern to search for inside matches
# repl - replacement text for the in-pattern matches
ReplacePatternBetweenTwoStrings <- function(left, right, x, what, repl) {
  left  <- gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", left)
  right <- gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", right)
  str_replace_all(x, 
     paste0("(?s)(?<=", left, ").*?(?=", right, ")"),
     function(z) gsub(what, repl, z)
  )
}

x <- "This is an example: this is another one, and this is yet another, and other, and so on."
ReplacePatternBetweenTwoStrings(":", ",", x, "\\s+", "_")
## => [1] "This is an example:_this_is_another_one, and this is yet another, and other, and so on."
```

See [this R demo](https://tio.run/##lVHBbsIwDL33K6xshwQC2q4IVGlfMG3cgKFQTFuppFWSigLj25mTUMZtmhUpjv2e7eeY67UqN0aZI7fOlDo3IkmeoMKdg1G8NnWrtwSgsCnzwsfj/ZDoKFjqpnXkHwoVMJhjB41yDo0GV4NFZbICdrUhqC23CHvlsgKtL4xNFThNpTLco3bgsHMB7Aokwqiv1JM@IvY9ht/QHRD1/FB/BhkWpiPYtTpzZa251yHj1BI6GUaUoZuAcwJRp2fktt1wxherxfnCxXDw9Xz@XpKl45VgEtgy2Cu5niKIGlfxL2qgeC5tfH2TvFZVxWkyipI1yjp8oWqpFTydzm79qIoYD1KezthdDRNMyMi6yz2JOM2vTAkn31AklyTp/LRsXpQW6CgN2Kl9U@GENt3Halq6gVqjpMf2njii65Mx8eDamvBj9te/cDbx25AsfARtxQ79e81Ecr3@AA).

**Replacing all whitespaces between the closest `:` and `,`**

This is a simple edge case of the above when `:[^:,]+,` matches a `:`, then any amount of chars other than `:` and `,` (the delimiter chars) and then a `,`, then the whitespaces are replaced with underscores in the matches only:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(x, ":[^:,]+,", function(z) gsub("\\s+", "_", z))
```

See the [regex demo](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsMgEEX3nmJwpcT2ANJjdNc0YtJpIlgNo4Ekl7dC21AYhvf/GxgqxbueLG0iZXJhJMnYCpcT8OvkEtSxAXC1r9mjhnx0MU9IEAOqGh6H2DD/5Ef8YYr1/szZ95HWFQzh7O2AxnovVgVc3zqt7o3iCp5LGLKLQewSxrT0grdtaqrgpq5dSlbKGw)

**Original answer** (scales rather poorly)

You may use the following regex:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|:)[^,]*?\K\s(?=[^,]*,)
```

Replace with `_`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4T3nJX/2).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|:)` - the end of the previous match (`\G(?!)^`) or a colon
- `[^,]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `,` as few as possible
- `\K`  - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=[^,]*,)`  - a positive lookahead check that makes sure there is a `,` after zero or more chars other than a comma.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/GnKflp):

```
re <- "(?:\\G(?!^)|:)[^,]*?\\K\\s(?=[^,]*,)"
x <- "This is an example: this is another one, and this is yet another, and other, and so on."
gsub(re, "_", x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "This is an example:_this_is_another_one, and this is yet another, and other, and so on."
```

Comment: `(?:\G(?!\A)|:)[^,]*?\K\h` would suffice.

Comment: @hwnd Only if there is a requirement to match spaces up to the end of the string if there is no comma after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly gross answer:

```
txt="This is an example: this is another one, and this is yet"

split_str=unlist(strsplit(gsub("^(.*:)(.*)(,.*)", "\\1$\\2$\\3", txt), split="$", fixed=T))

paste0(split_str[1], gsub(" ", "_",split_str[2]), split_str[3])
```